# How to Fetch multiple images in nodeJS?

Tags: html, node.js

So, problem is i have two jpg images you can see in HTML code. But only download.jpg is showing not lenovo.jpg but both are showing in the req.url
console image is attached and output is also attached.

[HTML output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqLjB.png)

[Console ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwMy0.png)

> this is my js file

```
//creating web server
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');     
var path = require('path');
 http.createServer(function(req,res){   

    if(req.url === "/"){        
        fs.readFile('./public/index.html',"UTF-8", function(err,html){
            res.writeHead(200,{'content-type': 'text/html'});
            res.end(html);
        });
    }
    else if(req.url.match("\.css$")){
        var cssPath = path.join(__dirname, '/public', req.url);
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(cssPath, "UTF-8");
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/css'});
        fileStream.pipe(res);
    }
    else if(req.url.match("\.jpg$")){
        var imagePath = path.join(__dirname,'/public',req.url);
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(imagePath);
        res.writeHead(200,{'content-type': 'image/jpg'});
        fileStream.pipe(res);
    }
    console.log(req.url);
 }).listen(3000);
```

> My Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- <meta charset="utf-8"> -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My HTML Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/base.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1> My First Heading From the Page of html </h1>
    <img src="./images/download.jpg">
    <img src="./images/lenovo.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you don't need to add another else if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at size of your lenovo.jpg image it have very high resolution please use low resolution or define width and height in img tag.

Comment: thanks sir it works my image have resolution 3861 * 2896 that is the problem. thanks you saved my day.

Comment: its okay be careful while using high resolution images

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a strict requirement not to use express, I suggest you to use express, and you can handle it with express' static file handling method:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html